# When will PHP 7.0.30 be available in official repositories?

Tags: php, release-management

There are security vulnerabilities in php 7.0.28.  I was wondering if there is a timeline of when I can expect 7.0.30 to be available in official repositories.

Thank you!

Comment: I've expanded upon my comment in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the Security Team for Ubuntu *prefers* to do updates is to patch the issue in the current version, rather than do a full version update.

Therefore, PHP 7.0.30 will most likely *never* land in Ubuntu Xenial's repositories.  This doesn't mean the security fixes *won't* be included though.

The Security team usually prefers to do individual patches for the individual CVEs against the existing version.  This takes some time, but they do eventually produce packages which have the fixes.

I've checked with my contacts on the Security Team and they have confirmed that the PHP fixes for the recent security issues which prompted the release of 7.0.30 and interim versions are in the pipeline for 'fixing', though they cannot guarantee an exact ETA for the release of the patches.